# Set-ItemProperty won't include newlines (powershell)

Tags: powershell, registry

I'm trying to use set-itemproperty to add an item to:
HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\Installation Sources

```
$InstallationSources = Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup" -Name "Installation Sources"
$test = $InstallationSources."Installation Sources" + "C:\Test\I386"
Set-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup" -Name "Installation Sources" "$test"
```

I can echo $test and it looks fine, several lines of paths with my addition at the end.
But when I actually use set-itempproperty, it squishes everything into one line, which doesn't work.  Each path needs to have its own line.  Even manually added newlines aren't passed in (ie: "`nC:\Test\I386").  Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve newlines then make sure the registry value is of type MultiString otherwise the registry won't allow the newlines AFAICT e.g.:

```
PS> New-ItemProperty hkcu:\ -Name bar -PropertyType MultiString
PS> Set-ItemProperty hkcu:\ -Name bar -Value "contents`r`nmore contents"
PS> Get-ItemProperty hkcu:\ -Name bar


PSPath       : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\
PSParentPath :
PSChildName  : HKEY_CURRENT_USER
PSDrive      : HKCU
PSProvider   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
bar          : {contents
               more contents}
```

Answer (score 0):

$test is an array of strings and powershell is automatically joining them together for you when you say:

```
"$test"
```

You need to do the join yourself, providing the correct separator character. i.e.:

```
Set-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup" -Name "Installation Sources" ($test -join "`n")
```